# PopOS Scaling multiple monitors individually

Tags: xorg, nvidia, multi-monitor

I have the latest PopOS with the NVIDIA 410 drivers running. I set up two monitors:

[image]

The 2nd monitor has 2160p, whereas the 1st has 1080p. I just want to scale the 2nd monitor (150% or 200%). The settings only offer 200%. If I change the scaling of monitor 2 to 200% the 1st monitor also scales to 200% which makes it unusable. I want to only scale the 2nd, leaving the 1080p as is. Altering the HiDPI daemon settings below did not lead to anything usable.

I also tried configuring it manually with xrandr --scale but it fails with an error. Just scaling the font is not enough, especially when using a VM inside.

Are there any suggestions?

---

Edit:

using `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --output DP-1 --primary  --mode 3840x2160 --transform "1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1" --left-of HDMI-0` or trying some Nvidia Settings in their GUI leads to a blurry desktop.

Comment: HI mate. did you ever managed to fix this?

Comment: Hey @jonneymendoza and matcauthon - Were any of you able to solve that?

Comment: Hej, I've solved it with some minor issues where it reset itself, but I'm not able to fully remeber what I've done. I think I followed the steps here: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/how-to-enable-hidpi-fractional-scaling.html?m=1 and that made it possible

Comment: No I have not resolved this issue

Answer (score 5):

This work for me（4k+1080P）

```bsh
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']"
```

[image]
[image]

(Just ignore the Chinese)

If that does not work for you, you also can try

```bsh
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['x11-randr-fractional-scaling','scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
```

From
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y50S5UnEOLw

Comment: did you need to reboot or anything? Or disable hidpi daemon? I'm not seeing any effect from either command.

Comment: @cacois I dont think this feature is supported on 20.04+ for PopOS since it's enabled by default on Ubuntu 20.04+ :(

Comment: @YashankVarshney man, that's sad. I haven't been able to work on my extra monitors because none of them are high dpi :(

Comment: @cacois yup... I think there is an open issue/conversation on PopOS reddit or forum regarding this, and their official statement was that they are not working on supporting fractional scaling at the moment. It's weird since it was working as an experimental feature before 20.04, and more over now it became official in 20.04 Ubuntu.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a link to any official statements - if you have one could you drop it here? I agree that sounds extremely odd, and its a core feature for many users.