# Different scales for join displays?

Tags: debian, gnome, display, monitors, resolution

Is it possible to have different scales for join displays? I tried the solution suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497040/popos-scaling-multiple-monitors-individually): `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']"` but it didn't do anything.

I have a laptop (with Debian 11 and Gnome 3 X11) with a 4K display and I got a second (portable) 1080p monitor.

For the main display, in Settings->Displays, I put a Scale of 200%. When I connect the second monitor, it works fine, but also has the 200% Scale, which makes it unusable.

I have the option to change the scale of the second monitor back to 100%, but then that automatically puts the scale of the primary display to 100% as well.

[image: Display settings]

Answer (score 1):

It now works (I can have different scales on either monitor) and I didn't have to do anything. I assume it's thanks to the Gnome upgrade (Gnome 40).

Comment: Update: For some reason (Gnome 41?), now it's back to the old situation: I can't have different scales.