# Is it possible to scale two displays differently?

Tags: x11, gnome, display, pop-os, resolution

I am using Ubuntu-based PopOs 22.04 LTS and I have two displays. One is my built-in display which has 2560x1440, and another external monitor has a 1920x1080 resolution. I enabled `Fractional scaling`, then set built-in display %125 and %100 external monitor. My built-in display scaled nicely but my external monitor just scaled horribly. It looks like %200.

Is there a way that I can scale my built-in display to %125 and external monitor to %100?

I have checked the below links but couldn't figure it out.

1. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1220077/is-it-possible-to-have-two-monitors-with-different-scales
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028622/different-display-scale-settings-18-04
3. https://askubuntu.com/questions/393400/is-it-possible-to-have-different-dpi-configurations-for-two-different-screens
4. https://askubuntu.com/questions/846279/scale-application-differently-on-different-monitors-ubuntu-16-04
5. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y50S5UnEOLw&ab_channel=LinuxLeech
6. [PopOS Scaling multiple monitors individually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497040/popos-scaling-multiple-monitors-individually)

Comment: I don't really have an answer for you but I encountered the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04 on my Lenovo Legion laptop. The scaling was horrible when the gpu mode was set to dynamic in the bios(it would use the hybrid GPU of my AMD processor by default and NVIDIA GPU based on the usage) but the different scales I set worked perfectly when I flipped the setting to always use the dedicated gpu in my bios. I had also installed the drivers for the AMD GPU from their website. This leads me to suspect that it must be an issue with the display drivers. AMD drivers have always been a pain with Ubuntu.